# Game screen jolts down and back up when closing a ChartBoost ad on android

Tags: android, chartboost

As the title says, when I receive a test ad, the ad comes down from the top and pushes the navigational bar off the screen. When I close the ad, the ad disappears, but my game screen moves down to try to fill up the space where the navigational bar was, only to be pushed back up by the navigational bar coming back on the screen. So every time an ad is closed, my game background moves down and then back up. Is their a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Above OS 4.4.2, Chartboost uses an ad format called webview. This is a completely separate activity that launches and takes control when an ad is shown. This is probably why you see some nav bar funkiness when the ad is dismissed and you activity gets control back.

I don't think there is a way around this without asking Chartboost directly as all of their most recent SDKs use the webview format.